# Finding a subset of the complex plane.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, geometry

I need to find $A=\{z\in \mathbb C :|\sin z| < \frac{1}{2} \}$. I need to shade $A$ on a graph sheet.

By separating the real and imaginary parts of $\sin z$, I concluded that $A=\{(x,y) | \sin^2 x + \sinh^2 y < \frac{1}{4} \}$. How do I continue to finish determining and shading $A$? Does Wolfram help here? Please post the shaded $A$ if possible. Advance thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper half of the form can be obtained resolving with respect to $y$
$$
y=\sinh^{-1}\sqrt{1/4-\sin^2 x}
$$
and the lower half
$$
y=-\sinh^{-1}\sqrt{1/4-\sin^2 x}
$$
and this repeats horizontally with period $\pi.$

Wolfram Mathematica code

```
RegionPlot[Abs[Sin[x + I y]] < 1/2, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    FrameTicks -> {Table[k \[Pi]/2, {k, -2, 2}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for the graph.